# Implication or equivalence in differentiation and integration

Tags: logic

Say we have $y'=2x+5$. Then if we differentiate $y'$ we have $y''=2$, and if we integrate it we have $y=x^2+5x+C$. Which of the following arrows correctly connects these two equations?

$$y'=2x+5\Longleftrightarrow y''=2$$
or
$$y'=2x+5\Longrightarrow y''=2$$

And
$$y'=2x+5\Longleftrightarrow y=x^2+5x+C$$
or
$$y'=2x+5\Longrightarrow y=x^2+5x+C$$

My guess is that for differenting $y'$ we should have the implication arrow, and for integrating we probably should have the equivalence arrow.

Comment: Your guess is correct. Do you have a justification for it?

Comment: @michaelhowes Yes! It was that when integrating $y''$ we do not have enough information to say that $C=5$. And for the differentiation of $y$, all's good since $dC/dx=0$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My guess is that for differenting $y′$ we should have the implication arrow, and for integrating we probably should have the equivalence arrow.

Why are you guessing?   Do you not have some reasoning, or at least intuition, for why this might be so?

$\implies$ indicates "is sufficient (but maybe not necessary) for".

- That is: $A\implies B$ guarantees that $B$ will be true if $A$ is, but does *not prohibit* $B$ from being true when $A$ is not.   $A$ is enough to derive $B$, but may not be needed (*having something else might do instead*).

$\iff$ indicates "is sufficent and necessary for".

- So if you can assert that $A$ is necessary for $B$, as well as sufficient, use $A\iff B$.   If you can only be certain that $A$ is sufficient for $B$ use $A\implies B$.

> Such as: $y''=2$ is derived from $y'= 2x+3$ but may *also* be derived from $y'=2x+A$ for any constant $A$ at all.   So having $y'=2x+3$ is *sufficient but not necessary* to derive $y''=2$.   Therefore $y'=2x+3\implies y''=2$ .